# Передать метод класса в качестве параметра

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, шаблоны-с++, методы

Не получается передать метод класса в качестве параметра.

Пример кода

```
class Cont
{
public:

    void add(int a)
    {
        m_vect.push_back(a);
    }

    template <class ModuleType>
    void map(ModuleType *module, void (ModuleType::*mapMethod)(int a))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_vect.size(); i++)
            (module->*mapMethod)(m_vect[i]);
    }

private:

    std::vector<int> m_vect;

};

class Oper
{
public: 
    void mapMethod1(int a)
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }

    void exec()
    {
        Cont cont;
        cont.add(1);
        cont.add(3);
        cont.add(4);

        cont.map<Oper>(this, mapMethod1); // **ошибка компиляции**
    }
};

int main()
{
    Oper oper;
    oper.exec();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так устроит?

```
cont.map<Oper>(this, &Oper::mapMethod1);
```

Вот полный код: https://ideone.com/DjiFoO

Comment: Да, так работает, спасибо.

Comment: Немного поспешил. Этот вариант отлично работает когда два класса описаны в одном файле. Если классы описаны в разных файлах линкер сообщает ошибку: undefined reference to `void Cont::map<Oper>(Oper*, void (Oper::*)(int))'

Comment: Ну так реализация шаблона обязана быть видна там, где он инстанцируется! Там, где выполняется вызов `cont.map`, обязан быть виден текст шаблона! Вы не можете выносить реализацию шаблонной функции в .cpp-файл и надеяться, что шаблон будет инстанцирован для вашего типа из другого файла - просто сами подумайте - *как?*

Answer (score 2):

Синтаксис для получения указателя на нестатическую функцию выглядит как `&ClassName::MethodName`. При чем в данном случае тип объекта может быть выведен из аргументов и можно не задавать его явно:

```
 cont.map(this, &Oper::mapMethod1);
```